# outlook shared calendar recurring item between the date specified range

Tags: vba, outlook

Following is my code where i can print the number of recurring items in the shared calendar folder. Now i want to take the date range from the user say SDate and EDate and want to check for the recurring as well the normal aapointment item between the specified date range and print it. My recurring item get start on 1/1/2010 and it has no enddate it recurs every friday. I want to check is that specific item get recur in between my date range or not, If yes want to print its details.

```
Sub item()

Dim objExpCal As Outlook.Explorer
Dim objNavMod As Outlook.CalendarModule
Dim objNavGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup
Dim objNavFolder As Outlook.NavigationFolder
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder

Set objOL = Application
Set objNS = objOL.Session
Set colExpl = objOL.Explorers

Set objExpCal = _
objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer

Set objNavMod = objExpCal.NavigationPane.Modules. _
GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)

Set objNavGroup = objNavMod.NavigationGroups. _
GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olPeopleFoldersGroup)


For Each objNavFolder In objNavGroup.NavigationFolders
    Set objFolder = objNavFolder.Folder
    Set oItems = objFolder.Items
    Set colFilteredItems = oItems.Restrict("[IsRecurring] = TRUE")

    For Each objItem In colFilteredItems

        Debug.Print objItem
        Set objpattern = objItem.GetRecurrencePattern

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Items.IncludeRecurrences property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171434(v=office.11).aspx